# How to move an object to the start of the array (index 0)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how do i most efficiently delete a particular object from an array and move it to the start

I have tried using regular logic like finding the index,manually splicing then splicing again to put the object on the top

```
farmer: [
{
id:1,
name: "name 1"
},
{
id:2,
name: "name 2"
},
{
id:3,
name: "name 3"
}
]
```

when i select farmer with id:2 i want to move it to the top

Comment: Can you show the "regular logic" you used?

Comment: what's the point of moving it to the top? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let idx = farmer.findIndex(f => f.id === 2)
farmer.unshift(farmer.splice(idx,1)[0])
```

Comment: Did the trick elegantly, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` together with `Array.unshift()` and `Array.push()`  functions like below:

```js
var farmer = [
  {id: 1, name: "name 1"},
  {id: 2, name: "name 2"},
  {id: 3, name: "name 3"}
];
var searchedId = 2;

var result = farmer.reduce(function(carry, item) {
  if (item.id === searchedId) {
     carry.unshift(item);
  } else {
     carry.push(item);
  }
  return carry;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

the JavaScript standard library does not offer any better method than locating the element by id, extracting it, and inserting it.

```js
let myArray = [{
 id: 1
}, {
 id: 2
}, {
 id: 3
}]

function moveItemById (array, id, position) {
 let elementIndex = array.findIndex((el) => {
   return el.id === id
  })
  if (!elementIndex) {
   return
  }
  
  array.splice(position, 0, array.splice(elementIndex, 1)[0])
}

moveItemById(myArray, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code :

```js
var farmer =  [
    {
  id: 1,
  name: "name 1"
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "name 2"
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: "name 3"
 }
]


farmerNew = farmer.filter(item => item.id !== 2);
selectedFarmer = farmer.filter(item => item.id === 2)[0];
farmerNew.unshift(selectedFarmer);
farmer = farmerNew
console.log(farmer)
```